# Package pxd defintions from different installed packages

Tags: cython, setuptools, python-3.8

I have an installed python module with cython extensions. Now I am writing a second (different) cython module that wants to import extensions from the installed cython module. However, it is not able to find the definition files of the first module.

The first module has `.../python3.8/site-packages/plexim[version]/EGG-INFO/SOURCES.txt` as follows:

```
setup.py
...
plexsim/models.cpp
plexsim/models.pxd
...
```

Which looks good as the `pxd` is packed with the module.

In the other module I want to import the pxd from `models.pxd`. However, when I try to install my other extensions module it cannot find the extension definition when doing

```
from plexsim.models cimport *
```

How do I package the data correctly such that the other module sees the definition from the already installed module?

My `setup.py` looks a follows

```
setup(
        package_dir  = {"" : "imi"
                        },
        namespace_packages     = find_namespace_packages (include = ["imi.*"]),
        package_data = {"": "*.pxd *.pyx".split(),
        ext_modules  = cythonize(
                exts,
                language_level      = 3,
                compiler_directives = cdirectives,
                nthreads            = mp.cpu_count(),
                ),\
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After hours of debugging I figured the path-issue out. Adding `__init__.pxd` to the module seemed to have cured the problem. For future reference be mindful of whether setuptools actually find the `pxd` files.